# how to delete a particular Row when timestamp as a index in python

Tags: python, dataframe

i am having a error while i am trying drop a row, 
i think problem occurs because my date is in a index

here is my data frame -:

```
                cast
   date          
2022-01-01      31.0
2022-01-02      01.0
2022-01-03      02.0
2022-01-04      12.0
2022-01-05     320.0
2021-01-06      04.0
```

here timestamp is in my index and i am not able to drop that last row using  `df.drop` i added some condition in it and applied on data frame .

error is `labels ['2021-01-06'] not contained in axis`

i use this in all the way , but it did not work out

thank you

Comment: How exactly do you attempt to drop it?

Comment: `2021-01-06      04.0` i want to drop this one @DYZ

Comment: Please read my question again. What code did you execute when you got that error message?

Comment: @DYZ  oh my bad , this one `df.drop('2021-01-06')`    and also tried many more operation but doesn't work any of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your index is apparently of type `DatetimeIndex`. You must convert the date to drop to the same datatype:

```
df.drop(pd.to_datetime('2021-01-06'))
```